# Gremlin Query: How to get all "internal" edges in the query so far?

Tags: database, graph, gremlin, tinkerpop

So I'm trying to visualize the nodes so far in a gremlin query together with only the edges between these nodes; the "internal" edges if you may.

For example, I have this gremlin query:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Person").out("Expert in")
```

which results in a set of nodes. How do I, in a general matter, make a gremlin query to get all the edges between the nodes in this resultset?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

This gremlin query should do the trick:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Person') // <-- Nodes chosen so far; can be any query resulting in nodes
.dedup()
.union(outE(), inE()) 
.groupCount()
.unfold()
.where(select(values).is(gt(1)))
.select(keys)
```

This takes the union of all outgoing and all ingoing edges, and then removes those edges that does not appear more than once. The result is all the edges between the nodes in the query so far :)

Answer (score 1):

The `out()` step is a shorthand for `outE().inV()` so the first step to getting the edges is to explicitly traverse the edges so that they become part of the path history. You could get the edges from that history in a variety of ways - how about the path() step?

```
g.V().hasLabel("Person").outE("Expert in").inV().path()
```

Comment: Thank you, but would this limit the returned edges to only be between the nodes returned from g.V().hasLabel("Person").out("Expert in") (which is what I want)? :)

Comment: Gremlin is constrained to the same "Expert in" edges in both your traversal and mine. In other words, there aren't other paths he can take to get from a "Person" to an adjacent vertex except by way of those edges, so yes, the results are the same except that now you have the edges as part of the result.